# What is the ruling on a person who repeats his prayer because he doubts his prayer was correct?

Tags: salat

What is the ruling on a person who repeats his prayers on account of doubts?

The prophet said to not pray the same prayer twice in one day.  So, if after a person has prayed in congregation he prays at home again because he believes that his prayer was incorrect or does not know the ruling on a particular mistake, which prayer will be accepted of him?  Or are both correct?

Answer (score 3):

If you follow (pray behind) the Imam you won't have to repeat a prayer, as he is [responsible](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/89) as the person who leads the prayer!

And normally people used to repeat a prayer they've done alone with a jama'a (as no one knows which one will be accepted) as mentioned in the sunan Books (except Ibn Majah)

> Jabir bin Yazid bin Al-Aswad Al Amir told us that his father said:
>
> "I
> attended Fajr prayer with the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)in Masjid Al
> Khaif.  When he finished praying, he saw two men at the back of the
> people who had not prayed with him.
>
> He said: 'Bring them here.' So
> they were brought to him, trembling. He said: 'What kept you from
> praying with us? They said: '0 Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) we have already
> prayed in our lodgings.'
>
> He said: 'Do not do that. If you have already
> prayed in your lodgings, then you come to a Masjid in which there is a
> congregation, then pray with them, and it will be a voluntary prayer
> for you."'
>
> (From Sunan [a-Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/10/82), Jami' [at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/71))

However if you are confused there's a fiqh rule saying "من شك في شيء بنى على اليقين" this may mean: If you are confused about something you've done you should only accept (build on) what you are sure about.
Therefore it could be ok to repeat your prayer in that case especially if you did it on your own!

**References and further Information:**
If you can read Arabic here are some fatwas and some suggestions i found on the matter or parts of it maybe they are helpful:

[1](https://ar.islamway.net/fatwa/12420/%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%A5%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9-%D8%B9%D9%86%D8%AF-%D9%83%D8%AB%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B3) (islamway),
[2](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/41889) (islamweb),
[3](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/140439) (islamweb),
[4](https://web.archive.org/web/20170716030921/http://www.tabibnafsany.com:80/weswas-tahara_ocd.html) (from a psychological PoV).

And here some English links for fatwas about having doubts about the validity of a prayer and repeating it:

[1](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=201190) (islamweb),
[2](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/100268/remedy-for-insinuating-whispers-that-has-to-do-with-purification-and-prayer) (islamqa)

A great [overview](http://www.islamic-laws.com/salatdoubts.htm) (it seems from shi'a point of view), i guess it could be very helpful!

And finaly an other interesting [post](https://islamandpsychology.blogspot.com/2011/01/overcoming-waswaas-whispers-in-ibaadat.html) with a psychological point of view!

Comment: I don't understand Arabic

Answer (score 0):

As-salamu alaykum,

Good Question ever saw. Let me explain your question.

Islam is a most beautiful religion in world(and forever). Islam never allows to do hard things.

Your question is about praying with doubt. Simply I agree with your argument about pray 2 times.

Every person in the world can't complete prayers 100%(not all, most of). Some one will miss `sujuud`, someone will miss `rukuh`... **To Complete prayers Islam is provide us `Sunnath prayers`**. Each and every main prayers(5 time), there is some prayers to complete before and after(Look at below image).

[image: table]

So **if you have any fault in main prayers it will be get covered by joining that sunnath  prayers**. So Complete all the prayers. It will only the main answer for your question

> As well as  after finish prayers(5 times prayers) there is zikker call `Astaghfiru-Llah`. You can immediately recite that after you giving second salam.
>   and there is another zikker to recite [after `maghrib` and after `sobh=fajr`](http://islamqa.info/en/6544) before speaking to any body!. That is `Allahumma Ajirnaa, Mina Naar`. Recite this zikker 7 times. This will cause to forgive your sin, if more than bubbles on sea.