# Do you redo prayer if you think about maybe stopping it and restarting it?

Tags: salat

During my Maghrib prayer, I accidentally cleared my throat for no reason (i think it is just a habit), and I wasn't sure whether or not I should re-do my prayer so I started to panic and paused for a few seconds to think about it, but i still kept my prayer pose with my hands on my heart and my eyes on the ground like they are supposed to.

I thought to be safe I should stop and re-start it, but then i changed my mind. It happened so fast. I physically wasn't moving, so to an outsider it did not look like i stopped praying because i kept my pose.

Should I re-do this prayer or was it okay to continue it? I suffer from waswas a lot and i though it was that, so i just continued the prayer.

Is this okay? 
Please let me know as I am very worried about it.

Comment: yes @Medi1Saif is right, and this should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you re-do it just to get sure that you've done it the right way that would be fine, but you shouldn't let this become a custom. In my maliki environment this actually seems to be practiced I'd say often in case of doubt etc.

But note that in your case sujud as-sahw would have been enough and you could do it any time!

Also read:
[What is the ruling on a person who repeats his prayer because he doubts his prayer was correct?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25905/what-is-the-ruling-on-a-person-who-repeats-his-prayer-because-he-doubts-his-pray)
[What is the correct manner to perform sujud sahw?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41517/what-is-the-correct-manner-to-perform-sujud-sahw)